# Prism Partial views xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I am using Prism to build xamarin forms apps.
I have never used Partial Views and cannot find any examples out there.

Can somebody point me to an example,so that I can see if fits what I am trying to achieve?

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Docs:](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/releases/tag/v7.1.0)

> The concept of a Partial View is to support a custom layout which may
>   be reused across multiple pages, and eliminate ViewModel logic
>   duplication by allowing that custom layout to rely on its own
>   ViewModel. To use a Partial View you must set the
>   ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView property with a reference to the
>   containing page as shown here. You should not set the
>   ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel property on the Partial View unless
>   you are explicitly opting out as setting this property to true
>   directly may result in the ViewModel being incorrectly set.

Example:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AwesomeApp.Views"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Ioc;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             x:Name="self"
             x:Class="AwesomeApp.Views.ViewA">
  <StackLayout>
    <local:AwesomeView mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutowirePartialView="{x:Reference self}" />
    <Entry Text="{Binding SomeValue" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Guys, my question is related to this. How can we use AutoWirePartialView in DateTemplateSelector ?

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer valid as of Prism 8. Had this working prior to updating but AutowirePartialView is no longer part of Prism's library. Unsure how to fix, but this came up during my search so thought best to keep anyone else up to date.